# ngrx 8 createAction syntax

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, ngrx

I am learning ngrx Angular now. I have little confusion with ngrx syntax.

I know that the below Syntax of arrow function simply return "customer" object.

```
export const addCustomer = createAction(

   '[Customer] Add Customer',
     (customer: Customer) => {customer}
);
```

But what is this Syntax? What does this below round brackets "({customer})" mean? Am I missing something of ES6?

```
export const addCustomer = createAction(

   '[Customer] Add Customer',
     (customer: Customer) => ({customer})
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(customer: Customer) => ({customer})` is a function which returns an object `{ customer: customer }`.

To understand it you need to be familiar with two concepts.

1. `() => ({})` is the same as `() => { return {}; }`.
2. `{ customer }` is the same as `{ customer: customer }`. Typescript allows such shortcuts in case property and variable names coincide (e.g. `customer` key and `customer` variable coincide in our case).